# Show that if $f$ is an analytic mapping of the unit disc into itself, then $|f'(0)|\le 1.$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that if $f$ is an analytic mapping of the unit disc into itself, then $|f'(0)|\le 1.$

This is related to the Schwarz Lemma, without the assumption that $f(0)=0$. My thought was to use the Möbius transformation
$$\varphi_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z},$$
which is a bijective analytic mapping of the unit disc. Let $f(0)=a$. If we consider the composition

$$F = \varphi_a\circ f\colon D_1(0)\to D_1(0)$$
then we have $F$ is an analytic mapping of the unit disc into itself with $F(0)=0.$ Now by Schwarz,

$$
\begin{align}
\left|F'(0)\right| &=\left|\varphi_a'(f(0)\cdot f'(0)\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{-1+a\bar{a}}{(1-a\bar{a})^2}\right|\cdot\left|\,f'(0)\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{1-|a|^2}\right|\cdot\left|\,f'(0)\right|\\&\le 1,
\end{align}
$$
which implies that $|\,f'(0)|\le1-|a|^2\le 1 $ since $a\in D_1(0).$

Does this seem correct? Obviously if $f(0)=0,$ then we have the conclusion of Schwarz automatically.

Comment: Can you show that it maps a unit-length interval into itself?

Comment: If the derivative is greater than 1, is a unit interval stretched?

Comment: You are correct. Not be confused.